# Hide the parameters in query string using GridMvc and ActionLink MVC C#

Tags: c#, post, model-view-controller, razor, datagrid

I am wondering if anyone could help me, the problem I have is that I am trying to not show the parameter in URL, when the parameter is posted to another controller. I have tried routing and changing the ActionLink. If anyone one could help it would be greatly appreciated.

I get "/Accounts/ViewCustomer/Index/3316", I want to hide 3316

Customer list view

```
   @Html.Grid(Model.CustomerList).Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Add(data => data.Referance).Titled("Reference").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).Filterable(true).
       RenderValueAs(model => Html.ActionLink(model.Referance, "Index", "ViewCustomer",
       routeValues: new { id = model.CustomerID },
       htmlAttributes: new { id = "cust" }).ToHtmlString());

       columns.Add(data => data.Company).Titled("Company").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).Filterable(true).
       RenderValueAs(model => Html.ActionLink(model.Company, "Index", "ViewCustomer", new { id =  model.CustomerID }, null).ToHtmlString());

   }).WithPaging(@ViewBag.Pagesize, @ViewBag.PageCountLimit).Sortable()
```

From view customer Controller to which int is posted

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        Paging paginginfo          = GridPageProvider.Pagesize();
        ViewData["Pagesize"]       = paginginfo.Pagesize;
        ViewData["PageCountLimit"] = paginginfo.PageCountLimit;

        SetCustomerInfo(id);

        if (_customerdetail.Contacts.Count != 0)
        {
            return View( _customerdetail);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case 3316 is part of your URL and you can't hide it. But you can send `id` as parameter (you will need change routing) and use POST method to hide it in method body